How to handle empty initial state in redux which is to be populated later
I am having some problem using redux with ts
my initial state is {} and later it is populated with keys and values
so when I try use that state in my component, its saying that this property does not exist on type {} even though I am sure that this component renders only after the state has been populated.
How can I fix this error?
I am trying to use it like this:
const TopSection = () => {
  const { username } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const mediaDetails: MediaDetailState = useAppSelector((state) => state.media);
  const { mediaid, mediaType } = mediaDetails;

  const routes = [
    { path: "/", title: "Overview" },
    { path: "watch", title: "Watch" },
    { path: "characters", title: "Characters" },
    { path: "staff", title: "Staff" },
    { path: "stats", title: "Stats" },
    { path: "social", title: "Social" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="bg-bgSecondary">
      {/* Backdrop image */}
      {mediaDetails.backdrop_path && (
        <div className="h-[25vh] md:h-[50vh] overflow-hidden">
          <img
            src={`${tmdbImgEndPoint}${mediaDetails.backdrop_path}`}
            alt={mediaType === "movie" ? mediaDetails.title : mediaDetails.name}
            className="object-top"
          />
        </div>
      )}
      {/* Poster and overview */}
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 px-12 md:px-56">
        {/* Poster and buttons */}
        <div className="col-span-12 md:col-span-2 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 md:block">
          <img
            src={
              mediaDetails.poster_path
                ? `${tmdbImgEndPoint}${mediaDetails.poster_path}`
                : posterPlaceholder
            }
            alt={mediaDetails.title}
            className={`${
              mediaDetails.backdrop_path ? "-mt-28" : "mt-2"
            } mb-4 rounded`}
          />
          {username && <Controls />}
        </div>
        {/* title and overview and links */}
        <div className="col-span-12 md:col-span-9 ms-0 md:ms-4 p-0 md:p-8 flex flex-col justify-between">
          <div className="mb-8 md:mb-0">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-normal">
              {mediaType == "movie" ? mediaDetails.title : mediaDetails.name}
            </h1>
            {mediaDetails.overview && (
              <p className="text-textLight text-[1.4rem] mt-6 hidden md:block">
                {mediaDetails.overview}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
          {/* Links */}
          <ul className="flex justify-around text-xl" id="pagenav">
            {routes.map((route) => (
              <Link
                className="hover:text-actionPrimary"
                to={`/${mediaType}/${mediaid}/${
                  route.path === "/" ? "" : route.path
                }`}
                key={route.title}
              >
                {route.title}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Redux:
export type ExtraMediaDetails = { mediaType: mediaTypeType; mediaid: number };
export type MediaDetailState =
  | (MovieDetail & ExtraMediaDetails)
  | (TvDetail & ExtraMediaDetails)
  | {};

let initialState: MediaDetailState = {};

export const mediaSlice = createSlice({
  name: "media",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setDetails: (state, action: PayloadAction<MediaDetailState>) => {
      Object.keys(state).forEach(
        (key) => delete state[key as keyof MediaDetailState]
      );
      for (const key in action.payload) {
        state[key as keyof MediaDetailState] =
          action.payload[key as keyof MediaDetailState];
      }
    },
    removeDetails: (state) => {
      Object.keys(state).forEach(
        (key) => delete state[key as keyof MediaDetailState]
      );
    },
  },
});

Here are rest of the types:
type MediaDetailBase = {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  homepage: string;
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  production_companies: ProductionCompany[];
  production_countries: ProductionCountry[];
  spoken_languages: Language[];
  status: string;
  tagline: string;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
};

export type MovieDetail = MediaDetailBase & {
  belongs_to_collection: string;
  budget: number;
  genre_ids: MediaDetailGenre[];
  imdb_id: string;
  original_title: string;
  release_date: string;
  revenue: number;
  runtime: number;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
};

export type TvDetail = MediaDetailBase & {
  created_by: TvCreator[];
  episode_run_time: number[];
  first_air_date: string;
  genres: MediaDetailGenre[];
  in_production: boolean;
  languages: string[];
  last_air_date: string;
  last_episode_to_air: Episode;
  name: string;
  next_episode_to_air: string;
  networks: Network[];
  number_of_episodes: number;
  number_of_seasons: number;
  origin_country: string[];
  original_name: string;
  seasons: Season[];
  type: string;
};


I was trying to use redux with typescript
I initialised my state as {}
and later it is to be populated
but ts is showing error that the state might be {} while fetching it from useSelector()
It is the expected behavior.
I want to know to setup redux with ts so that these things don't happen

You could make the initial state include mediaType and  mediaid as optional. Something like {} & Partial<ExtraMediaDetails>.
export type ExtraMediaDetails = {
  mediaType: mediaTypeType;
  mediaid: number
};

export type MediaDetailState =
  | (MovieDetail & ExtraMediaDetails)
  | (TvDetail & ExtraMediaDetails)
  | ({} & Partial<ExtraMediaDetails>);


ExtraMediaDetails is indeed of the type { mediaType: mediaTypeType; mediaid: number }; But mediaid and mediaType are not the only
properties that I am trying to extract from the state there are other
properties such as title, poster_path which are defined in
MovieDetail or TvDetail but not in ExtraMediaDetails

For this you'll need to test for which type you have at runtime. I often suggest adding a type property based on generics.
Example:
type MediaDetailBase<T extends string> = {
  type: T;
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  homepage: string;
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  production_companies: ProductionCompany[];
  production_countries: ProductionCountry[];
  spoken_languages: Language[];
  status: string;
  tagline: string;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
};

Then type the MovieDetail and TvDetail types:
export type MovieDetail = MediaDetailBase<"Movie"> & {
  belongs_to_collection: string;
  budget: number;
  genre_ids: MediaDetailGenre[];
  imdb_id: string;
  original_title: string;
  release_date: string;
  revenue: number;
  runtime: number;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
};

export type TvDetail = MediaDetailBase<"TV"> & {
  created_by: TvCreator[];
  episode_run_time: number[];
  first_air_date: string;
  genres: MediaDetailGenre[];
  in_production: boolean;
  languages: string[];
  last_air_date: string;
  last_episode_to_air: Episode;
  name: string;
  next_episode_to_air: string;
  networks: Network[];
  number_of_episodes: number;
  number_of_seasons: number;
  origin_country: string[];
  original_name: string;
  seasons: Season[];
  type: string;
};

I think MediaDetailState can be simplified just a tad to:
export type MediaDetailState =
  | ((MovieDetail | TvDetail) & ExtraMediaDetails)
  | {};

And in your UI code where you access the state.media value check the type property and cast to the appropriate type to access the correct runtime properties.
Example:
const mediaDetails: MediaDetailState = useAppSelector((state) => state.media);

if ("type" in mediaDetails) {
  switch (mediaDetails.type) {
    case "Movie": {
      // Cast as MovieDetail & ExtraMediaDetails
      const {
         mediaType,
         mediaid,
         // Other MovieDetail properties
      } = mediaDetails as MovieDetail & ExtraMediaDetails;
      break;
    }
    case "TV": {
      // Cast as TvDetail & ExtraMediaDetails
      const {
        mediaType,
        mediaid,
         // Other TvDetail properties
      } = mediaDetails as TvDetail & ExtraMediaDetails;
      break;
    }
  }
} else {
  // just the empty object
}


ExtraMediaDetails is indeed of the type  {
mediaType: mediaTypeType;
mediaid: number
};
But mediaid and mediaType are not the only properties that I am trying to extract from the state
there are other properties such as title, poster_path which are defined in MovieDetail or TvDetail but not in ExtraMediaDetails

@TahirReyaz I see, then I think you'll need a more explicit null check in your UI code to determine which sub-type you are actually able to work with. Can you edit the post to include a more accurate [mcve] for what you are trying to do?

I learnt some things in this answer but the properties which are extracted in the switch case block will be accessible only inside those code blocks
They are not accessible in my return statement of the component where I am using these properties
There, its saying that cannot find mediaType and mediaid
also Property 'backdrop_path' or 'title' or 'name' does not exist on type '{}'

@TahirReyaz I have only provided an example for how to check the runtime type to be able to access the correct properties. It's left as an exercise for you to apply this to your actual code to fit your needs. You could do inline checks if you wanted, something like {"type" in mediaDetails && mediaDetails.type === "Movie" && (mediaDetails as MovieDetail).backdrop_path && /* JSX accessing (mediaDetails as MovieDetail) */}. Does this make sense?

@TahirReyaz Actually, since it looks like your JSX only cares about the base media details, e.g. backdrop_path and poster_path, you could cast to the more general type, something like {"type" in mediaDetails && (mediaDetails as MediaDetailBase<any>).backdrop_path. If you don't care whether it's movie or tv details, then check if it's not either of these and early return something else so that when you get to the JSX return you know you can access the base properties without needing that type check each time.

Thanks
I removed redux and used react query for the because I was fetching the media details in the parent component already
Also your suggestion for using (mediaDetails.title) as MovieDetail also helped when title or name was need

@TahirReyaz Welcome, happy to help. Cheers!
